# Sub Domain Routing in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, subdomain

Hello i am new to AngularJS, i have done my research and i know redirecting to a sub domain will cause the page to refresh.  What i want to know is how to check what the sub domain is when a link is clicked and load the right view and controller.

I use wildcard sub domains but i basically have three of them right now:

1. **administrator**.example.com
2. **manager**.example.com
3. **employee**.example.com

Each sub-domain should redirect you to their respective dashboard view and controllers.

The main url however example.com shall direct you to the website itself.

I have set-up my states like this:

```
app

app.administrator
app.administrator.dashboard

app.manager
app.manager.dashboard

app.employee
app.employee.dashboard
```

Comment: You should have separate angular apps for each of domains with it's own routing, controllers and etc.

Comment: You would need to parse the url

Comment: @Grievoushead not if the app is the same for all 3 and the only difference is a domain variable

Comment: The app is the same as in same template, the differences are the view controllers etc.

Comment: @user3718908 are you good in creating angular directive?

Comment: Yes i know how to create a directive.

Comment: ok, let me create plunker for you.

Comment: @user3718908 what do you mean by 'app is the same for all 3'? I think at least dashboard should show diff data for manger and employee, isn't it?

Comment: "The app is the same as in same template, the differences are the view controllers etc"

Comment: @user3718908 so, you are saying, that depending on domain you need to load certain controllers, view and etc (which in my opinion is an app). Probably I didn't understood your idea, but i think it's better to create separate client app for certain domains and reuse some shared services and the api backend if needed. To answer you question 'what is sub domain' you can utilize angular $location.host();

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense, thank you very much.

Comment: @user3718908 Just posted answer , Please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Here i am going to give you standard solution to your problem. You should create a separate application for each subdomain. I have created a sample application to demonstrate the flow.

**Index.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.0.0" data-semver="2.0.0" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="app.manager.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <load-application></load-application>
  </body>

  </html>
```

**app.js**

```
  /**
   * @name app
   * 
   * Lets create angular application module
   * if second parameter is passed with enpty array [] or with dependecies , is    * called angular module setter
   * 
   * angular.module('app', []); Setter
   * angular.module('app'); Getter
   */
  angular
    .module('app', ['appLoader']);

  /**
   * app.administrator application for aministrator subdomain
   */
  angular
    .module('app.administrator', ['ui.router']);

  /**
   * app.employee application for employee subdomain
   */
  angular
    .module('app.employee', ['ui.router']);


  /**
   * Lets create a application loader
   * This component is going to load sub domain specific application
   */
  angular
    .module('appLoader', ['app.administrator', 'app.manager', 'app.employee'])
    .directive("loadApplication", ['$location', function($location) {
      function getDomain() {
        console.log($location.host());
        //get domain name here
        return 'manager';
      }
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {},
        template: function() {
          var domainName = getDomain(),
            templateName = '';
          switch (domainName) {
            case 'manager':
              templateName = '<app-manager></app-manager>';
              break;
            case 'employee':
              templateName = '<app-employee></app-employee>';
              break;
            case 'administrator':
              templateName = '<app-administrator></app-administrator>';
              break;
          }
          return templateName;
        },
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
          console.info('loader application');
        }
      };

    }]);


  angular
    .module('app.administrator')
    .directive("appAdministrator", ['$location', function($location) {

      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<h2>{{applicationName}}</h2>',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
          $scope.applicationName = 'Application Administrator';
        }
      };

    }]);

  angular
    .module('app.employee')
    .directive("appEmployee", ['$location', function($location) {

      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<h2>{{applicationName}}</h2>',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
          $scope.applicationName = 'Application Employee';
        }
      };

    }]);
```

**app.manager.js**

```
 angular
    .module('app.manager', ['ui.router']);

  angular
    .module('app.manager')
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
      $stateProvider
        .state('index', {
          url: '/',
          template: '<ul><li><a ng-href="#" ui-sref="demopage1">Demo page 1</a></li><li><a ng-href="#" ui-sref="demopage2">Demo page 2</a></li></ul>'
        })
        .state('demopage1', {
          url: '/demopage1',
          template: '<ul><li><a ng-href="#" ui-sref="demopage1">Demo page 1</a></li></ul>'
        })
        .state('demopage2', {
          url: '/demopage2',
          template: '<ul><li><a ng-href="#" ui-sref="demopage1">Demo page 1</a></li></ul>'
        })
    });

  angular
    .module('app.manager')
    .directive("appManager", ['$location', function($location) {

      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<h2>{{applicationName}}</h2><div ui-view></div>',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
          $scope.applicationName = 'Application Manager';
        }
      };

    }]);
```

[Working plunker is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/eUaYYvxWkKWovD0JTWjy?p=preview)

I have created 3 applications for three domains , each application works independently. I have implemented the UI routes in **app.manager** application. You can implement the same in rest applications.

Lets me know if you have any concern ?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't started using the routing module called **ui.router** in your angular-based app, I suggest you read it [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). I believe it is much more powerful than the `ngRoute` module native in Angular 1.x.

From my understanding your subdomain, I think you can arrange them as nested domains (or to be more precise, states) under '`app`'. If the root url of your 'app' is something like '`/main/`', then the subdomains will inherit that root url and take the form such as '`/main/administrator`' and '`/main/administrator/dashboard`'

Each state (including nested states) can have its own controller, in which you can use the `$state` service in `ui.router` to get the state name (or subdomain name as you said) by calling: `$state.$current.name`

I hope this helps

As an example from my previous work. Here the main app has the url '`/webapp`', and the rest of the states are nested states that have their url started with '`/webapp`', e.g. for  the state '`home.blogs`', its url is '`/webapp/blogs`'. If it's still confusing, I suggest you spend some time reading the documentation on ui.router at Github.

```
angular
  .module('blogFrontendApp', [
    'ui.router'
  ])

config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/webapp/blogs');

    $stateProvider.state('home', {
     // abstract: true,
      url: '/webapp',
      views: {
        '' : {
          templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
        },
        'rightPanel@home' : {
          templateUrl: 'views/rightPanel.html'
        },
        'mainContent@home' : {
          templateUrl: 'views/mainContent.html'
        }
      }
    })

      .state('home.blogs', {
        //to be shown in mainContent@home
        url: '/blogs',
        templateUrl: 'views/home_blogs.html'
      })

      .state('home.singleBlog', {
        url: '/blog/:blogId/:blogTitle',
        templateUrl: 'views/single_blog.html',
        controller: 'blogArticleController as currentBlogView',
        resolve: {
          BlogService : 'BlogService',
          blogObj : function(BlogService, $stateParams) {
            return BlogService.getBlogById($stateParams.blogId);
          }
        }
      })

      .state('home.blogListInCategory', {
        url: '/blogs/category/:categoryId',
        templateUrl: 'views/blog_list_in_category.html',
        controller: 'blogListController as blogListView'
      })

      .state('home.publishBlog', {
        url: '/blogs/:categoryId/new',
        templateUrl: 'views/publish_blog.html',
        controller: 'blogListController as writeBlogView'
      })
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying, i am using ui-router although i am pretty new to it so i'm a bit confused by your answer, could you please show me an example.